# How to shift a record from one view to another view through workflow in crm 2011 on-premise

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

How do I shift a record from one view to another view that is a custom view through workflow?

I want a functionality such that when a record is processed and saved it should shift from "Active" view to another view named as "Processed" through workflow. Right now it is giving me the option to shift it from Active to Inactive on "Change Record Status."

is this even possible? or is there a workaround?

Comment: What you want can be achieved through a custom view, filtered on an attribute value, a workflow should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom view "Processed" shows the records based on certain conditions (for example a view can show the records recently created or where a field contains a certain value).

So inside the workflow you need to update the fields that make a record belongs to the custom view "Processed".

Comment: and how do I remove the same record from the default view "Active?" I want the same record to move from one view to another. Even if the record is moved to Processed by what you said, how can I hide it from Active?

Comment: If your "Processed" records are not visible inside the default "Active" view, means that they are **also** inactive.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and help Guido Preite.